# Vue-i18n syntax to replace input value (equal to v-model)

Tags: vue.js, vue-i18n

To add translation feature to an VueJS3 app, I'm following:
https://vue-i18n.intlify.dev/guide/essentials/syntax.html
all examples use this sintax  `<p>{{ $t('message.hello'}}</p>`

Let's use this messages as value in an input element:

```
const messages = {
  en: {
    message: {
      hello: 'hello world'
    }
  }
}
```

But I'm not able to figure out how to replace current static input value:

```
<input type="submit" value="TODO" class="button primary" />
```

If I use vue model it works fine:

```
<input type="submit" v-model="thisisfromvue" class="button primary" />
```

But how do I use i18 value message.hello?

```
<input type="submit" v-model="$t('message.hello')" class="button primary" />

[plugin:vite:vue] v-model value must be a valid JavaScript member expression.
```

Comment: This isn't what v-model is for. Please, clarify how exactly it's supposed to work because this interferes with value that a user inputs

Comment: Thanks for the comment, this should translate the visible text on the submit button based on the current selected locale.

Comment: If a value is permanent then it's `:value="$t('message.hello')"`. v-model is sugar syntax, it's explained in the docs what it means

Comment: @EstusFlask thanks! I'll keep note v-model use is wrong, many thanks.